# Handling cookies in a seperate class file in C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have made a Single Sign On system and I am making a class library for handling cookies.
But I am not able to get the server (ASP.NET MVC Controlller) instance into the class library.
Please find attached my .cs file in which I have methods that can handle all cookies in my application.
Should I pass the HTTPContext object from my web application to the class library (into the method) or the Response object?
I have tried both but in vain!

```
public void DoLogin(string username, bool autoSignIn)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["nowenableLogin"]["username"] = username;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["nowenableLogin"]["autoSignIn"] = autoSignIn.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["nowenableLogin"]["lastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["nowenableLogin"]["status"] = true.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["nowenableLogin"].Expires = autoSignIn ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) : DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: You cant't, unless you were to inject the `HttpContext` from the controller into the class.

Comment: Is there a way to inject the HttpContext into the class?

Comment: You can just add a parameter `public void DoLogin(string username, bool autoSignIn, HttpContext context)` but I suspect you would be better off moving this method to a `BaseController : Controller` class (which will have access to the `HttpContext`) and have all your controllers that need access it it inherit from `BaseController`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions....

Answer (score 1):

> I have had the same problem, while trying to read a "cshtml" file.
>    I saved it in a variable, and sent it as a body in an email. The way i solved
>   it, was by creating a new instance of a controller inside the
>   controller class (where the method from helper class was called giving
>   it parameters). But in this case, you just need HttpContext, so replacing my idea of ControllerContext, in this way it would be using

This snippet in controller:

```
 HelperClass.DoLogin("username",true,HttpContext.Current);
```

And then, in the helper class you can just use:

```
public void DoLogin(string username, bool autoSignIn,HttpContext context)
{
     var cookie = context.Response.Cookies["cookieName"];
}
```